# ReferenceError: [tablename] is not defined | Node.js, Express, Axios, PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, axios

I am trying to build a web app and I really have problems when it comes to the database connection.

I am currently working with his Tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize
And my client and also the server are working.

But now I have to do the database access. For that reason I am using Postman to try out my POST- and GET-Statements.

Everytime when I am trying the following GET-Statement:

> localhost:8000/api/tools

I just get

> ```
> ReferenceError: Tools is not defined
>               
>     at list (server\controllers\tools.js:17:5)
>               
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>               
>     at next (server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>               
>     at Route.dispatch (server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> ```

And I really don't get why it always says "Tools is not defined".
I have a database scheme called "public".
So maybe that could be a thing? 
I also tried to set database to public.[DATABASENAME] but it doesn't changed a thing.

I hope you guys can help me and I described the case good enough.

My files for that looks like that:

**/server/config/config.json**

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "[USERNAME]",
    "password": "[PASSWORD]",
    "database": "testdb",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": [PORT],
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
const toolsController = require('../controllers').tools;
const toolitemsController = require('../controllers').toolitems;

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/api', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the tools API!',
  }));

  app.post('/api/tools', toolsController.create);
  app.get('/api/tools', toolsController.list);
  app.get('/api/tools/:toolId', toolsController.retrieve);
  app.put('/api/tools/:toolId', toolsController.update);
  app.delete('/api/tools/:toolId', toolsController.destroy);

  app.post('/api/tools/:toolId/items', toolitemsController.create);
  app.put('/api/tools/:toolId/items/:toolitemId', toolitemsController.update);
  app.delete(
    '/api/tools/:toolId/items/:toolitemId', toolitemsController.destroy
  );
  app.all('/api/tools/:toolId/items', (req, res) => res.status(405).send({
    message: 'Method Not Allowed',
  }));
};
```

**/server/controllers/tools.js**

```
const tool = require('../models').tool;
    const toolitem = require('../models').toolitem;

    module.exports = {
      create(req, res) {
        return Tools
          .create({
            tool_id: req.body.tool_id,
            tool_name: req.body.tool_name,
            status: req.body.status
          })
          .then((tools) => res.status(201).send(tools))
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      },

      list(req, res) {
        return Tools
          .all()
          .then(tools => res.status(200).send(tools))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
      },
    };
```

edited Version of **/server/controllers/tools.js**

`const tools = require('../models').tools;
const toolitem = require('../models').toolitem;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return tools
      .create({
        tool_id: req.body.tool_id,
        tool_name: req.body.tool_name,
        status: req.body.status
      })
      .then((tools) => res.status(201).send(tools))
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  list(req, res) {
    return tools
      .all()
      .then(tools => res.status(200).send(tools))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
  /*
  list(req, res) {
    return tool
      .findAll({
        include: [{
          model: toolitem,
          as: 'toolitems',
        }],
        order: [
          ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
          [{ model: toolitem, as: 'toolitems' }, 'createdAt', 'ASC'],
        ],
      })
      .then((tools) => res.status(200).send(tools))
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },*/

  retrieve(req, res) {
    return tools
      .findById(req.params.toolId, {
        include: [{
          model: toolitem,
          as: 'toolitems',
        }],
      })
      .then((tools) => {
        if (!tools) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'tools Not Found',
          });
        }
        return res.status(200).send(tools);
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  update(req, res) {
    return tools
      .findById(req.params.toolId, {
        include: [{
          model: toolitem,
          as: 'toolitems',
        }],
      })
      .then(tools => {
        if (!tools) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'tools Not Found',
          });
        }
        return tools
          .update({
            title: req.body.title || tool.title,
          })
          .then(() => res.status(200).send(tools))
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  destroy(req, res) {
    return tools
      .findById(req.params.toolId)
      .then(tools => {
        if (!tools) {
          return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'tool Not Found',
          });
        }
        return tools
          .destroy()
          .then(() => res.status(204).send())
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};`

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the Tools model? This error is very similar when we forget to create a model.

`node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:generate --name Tools --attributes field1:string,field2:string,field3:integer`

When we use Sequelize, we need to create a model and after that run the migration.

Follow the documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :**

> ReferenceError: Tools is not defined
>
> ```
> at list (server\controllers\tools.js:17:5)
> ```

**The issue itself explains , file is tools.js and line no is 17.**

Here you have imported

```
const tool = require('../models').tool;
```

and you are using

```
Tools.create(...
```

**Solution : Change that to**

```
tool.create(
```

Comment: That does not change a thing. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @SnakeEyes , have changed that everywhere ? I can see that 2 times from given code, please check other places too, coz this is the only issue you are geting error.

Comment: `list (server\controllers\tools.js:17:5)` as you can see that its also showing the file and the line number.

Comment: Okay, now I get "TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;all&#39; of undefined <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at list (server\controllers\tools.js:18:8)

Comment: I have addet the full content of my edited tools.js to the question. Maybe that helps. I think that is a little bit confusing with the whole "tool" and "tools" thing.

Comment: @SnakeEyes , the error you have mentioned is already solved now this is diff error , of `tools.all()` because there is no such method provided by sequlize , you can use `tools.findAll()`. for more methods read http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html